# How to use CircularProgressIndicator in register button flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm newbie in flutter and wanted to know what is better way to add CircularProgressIndicator in my layout. I have designed SignUp screen and integrated API on button click. I want to show the CircularProgressIndicator when user click on the button and dismiss it when API execution is finished.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

```
class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  //  String name, email, phone, location

  Authentication authentication = Authentication();
  final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('User enregistré avec succès'));
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  /* @override
  void dispose() {
 
    super.dispose();
  }*/

  // final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(3, 9, 23, 1),
        body: Background(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FadeAnimation(
                      1.2,
                      Center(
                          child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Text('Tracar vous dit Bonjour',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: Color(0xC2DEB522))),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Text('Inscrivez-vous SVP',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: Color(0xFFCFCFCC).withOpacity(0.5)))
                        ],
                      )),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    FadeAnimation(
                        1.5,
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withOpacity(0.9)),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey[400]))),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _emailController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                      hintText: " Adresse mail"),
                                  validator: (String value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Entrez votre adresse email';
                                    }
                                    if (!RegExp(
                                            "^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")
                                        .hasMatch(value)) {
                                      return 'Entrez email valide';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                             
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey[400]))),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _nameController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                      hintText: " Nom"),
                                  validator: (String value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Entrez votre nom';
                                    }
                                    if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]")
                                        .hasMatch(value)) {
                                      return 'Entrez un nom valide';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  /* onSaved: (String value) {
                                        name = value;
                                      },*/
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey[400]))),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _phoneController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                      hintText: "N° Tel"),
                                  validator: (String value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Entrez votre num Tel ';
                                    }
                                    if (!RegExp('^(?:[+0][1-9])?[0-9]{10,12}')
                                        .hasMatch(value)) {
                                      return 'Entrez un num Tel valide';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  /*  onSaved: (String value) {
                                        name = value;
                                      },*/
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey[400]))),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _usernameController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                      hintText: "Nom utilisateur"),
                                  validator: (String value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Entrez votre psudo';
                                    }
                                    if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]")
                                        .hasMatch(value)) {
                                      return 'Entrez une psudo valide';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  /* onSaved: (String value) {
                                        name = value;
                                      },*/
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey[400]))),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _passwordController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  obscureText: _isHidden,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                    hintText: "Mot de passe",
                                    suffix: InkWell(
                                        onTap: _togglePasswordView,
                                        child: Icon(
                                            _isHidden
                                                ? (CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                    .eye_outline)
                                                : (CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                    .eye_off),
                                            color: Color(0xFF939394))),
                                  ),
                                  validator: (String value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Entrez votre mot de passe';
                                    }
                                    if (!RegExp(
                                            "^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}")
                                        .hasMatch(value)) {
                                      return 'Entrez une mot de passe valide';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  /* onSaved: (String value) {
                                        name = value;
                                      },*/
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey[400]))),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _password_confirmationController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  obscureText: _isHidden,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                    hintText: "Confirmer mot de passe",
                                    suffix: InkWell(
                                        onTap: _togglePasswordView,
                                        child: Icon(
                                          _isHidden
                                              ? (CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                  .eye_outline)
                                              : (CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                  .eye_off),
                                          color: Color(0xFF939394),
                                        )),
                                  ),
                                  validator: (String value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Retapez mot de passe';
                                    }
                                    //   print(password.text);
                                    //  print(confirmpassword.text);
                                    if (_passwordController.text !=
                                        _password_confirmationController.text) {
                                      return "Mot de passe incorrect";
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                        bottom: BorderSide(
                                            color: Colors.grey[400]))),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _adressController,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                      hintText: " Adresse "),
                                  validator: (String value) {
                                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Entrez votre adresse ';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                  /*  onSaved: (String value) {
                                        name = value;
                                      },*/
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                    //SizedBox(height: 40,),
                    FadeAnimation(
                        1.8,
                        Center(
                            child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: RaisedButton(
                                    textColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                                    child: Text("S'inscrire"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                        registerUser();
                                      }
                                    },
                                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  width: 250,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
                                  login: false,
                                  press: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) {
                                          return LoginPage();
                                   

  void _togglePasswordView() {
    setState(() {
      _isHidden = !_isHidden;
    });
  }

  void registerUser() async {
    // if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;
    String name = _nameController.text;
    String username = _usernameController.text;
    String phone = _phoneController.text;
    String adress = _adressController.text;
    String password_confirmation = _password_confirmationController.text;

    authentication
        .register(name, email, phone, password, password_confirmation, username,
            adress)
        .then((user) {
      if (user != null)
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      /* setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });*/
    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
    });
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
```

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Future Builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and set your Future Function (`registerUser`) in `future` attribute. You can control the visible widget based on the status of your function. So you dont have to use `isloading` variable.
Need to change `registerUser` to `Future`:

```
Future registerUser() async{
 return authentication.register...
}
```

Comment: it's works but didn't show me CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: Debug snapshot and check when is loading. Maybe your function doesnt return a Future correctly or something was wrong with your loading widget.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your existing isLoading variable or create another one. Initially set it to false and then, on button click, set its state to true.

```
RaisedButton(
   textColor: Colors.white,
   color: kPrimaryColor,
   child: isLoading ? circularProgressIndicator() : Text("S'inscrire"),
   onPressed: () {
   if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
       registerUser();
   },
   shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius:
         new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
   ),
   width: 250,
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
)
```

I hope it could help you!
If not, just response.

Comment: it's works but didn't show me CircularProgressIndicator

Comment: @lucky you need to use setstate and set isLoading to true on onpressed!

Comment: like this ? :       onPressed: () {
                                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          setState(() {
                                            isLoading = true;
                                          });
                                        });
                                        registerUser();
                                      }
                                    },

Answer (score 0):

The `isLoading` is set correctly.
Now you could do the following

```
class LoadingExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) :  //... your page content,
    );
  }
}
```

This checks if loading is true. When true it returns the the CircularProgressIndicator, else your Page Content.